# Algorithm : Generate QuadKeys for different zoom

Tags: c#, algorithm, bing-maps

I want to know if there is an algorithm ready to use to generate quadkeys for different zoom.

A quadkey represents a unique picture in the globe and when we zoom in we split a quadkey into 4 other quadkeys (or pictures), and my objective is to generate all the quadkeys from the initial zoom to the target zoom, for example

**Inputs :**

**033111010230** *(this is a random quadkey with zoom 12 because it contains 12digits)*

**14** *(this is the zoom target)*

**Ouputs :**

**033111010230** *(quadkey itself zoom 12)*

**0331110102300** *(first quadkey splited from the original quadkey)*

**03311101023000** *(first quadkey splited from the one with zoom 13)*

**03311101023001**

**03311101023002**

**03311101023003**

**0331110102301** *(second quadkey splited from the original quadkey)*

**03311101023010**

**03311101023011**

...

**03311101023033**

I don't want you to develop this algorithm for me i just here asking if there is an algorithm ready to use, I've read this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx) about some quadkey key algorithms but it only talks about conversions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is interested about this kind of algorithm :

```
public static void SplitQuadKey(string quadKey, int zoom)
        {
            if (quadKey.Length < zoom)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(quadKey + j);
                    SplitQuadKey(quadKey + j, zoom);
                }
            }
        }
```